# python time module: daylight savings

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, dst

I have a question about python's `time` module specifically (*not* asking about `datetime`, `pytz`, or any other module).

How can I find out, using the `time` module, whether it is currently daylight savings time (DST) in the place and date where I currently am?

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) seems vague on this topic. I would have thought that `time.daylight` would be 0 if it's currently standard time (winter) vs nonzero if it's currently daylight time (summer), based on my interpretation of how the docstring is worded: `Nonzero if a DST timezone is defined.`

However, it seems that this is not what `time.daylight` does! Currently it is winter (standard) time here, but `time.daylight == 1`

How can I use the `time` module to find out if it is currently DST? Or is this impossible? Thanks!

Comment: related: [Use Python to find out if a timezone currently in daylight savings time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19774709/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find out, using the `time` module, whether it is currently daylight savings time (DST) in the place and date where I currently am?

Assuming your computer is set to the correct timezone:

```
import time

is_dst = time.daylight and time.localtime().tm_isdst > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my system. Maybe your OS is set to DST?

Comment: What do you mean by "my os is set to DST"?  If I use a high-level module such as the one described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12015245/402807 , it correctly reports my timezone as "PST" (Pacific Standard Time)

Comment: Your system may set DST automatically or it may let you do it manually. But if other modules dump the correct information, this cannot be the reason.

Comment: To clarify: when you say "this works on my system", are you saying that all of these things are true for you:

(1) you live in a geographic area that does indeed utilize DST (e.g. the continental USA) , (2) is it currently not DST (you are in the winter) , and (3) `time.daylight == 0` ?

Comment: Currently I am in Malaysia and `time.daylight == 0` which is correct. When connecting to a machine in Germany `time.daylight == 1` which is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

[pytz](http://pythonhosted.org//pytz/) is good way to handle timezones, local time conversions and DST in python consistently.
Sorry for not posting an actual example of usage but it's a good idea to go through the module docs to see the various pitfalls and use cases of DST conversion.

Comment: Thanks, but in my question I specifically said in the first sentence that I'm not asking about `pytz`. I agree that for most practical cases `pytz` would be the way to go, but I'm curious specifically about the `time` module, hence this question.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I must have read your post a bit fast the first time.