# tz.gettz() return None in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.7

I am trying to convert UTC time to local time zone using below code. it's working fine on ubuntu 18.04. But getting an error in windows 10. Because `tz.gettz()` return `None`.

In command prompt getting below error:

> astimezone() argument 1 must be datetime.tzinfo, not None.

Here is the code:

```
from dateutil import tz
def convert_to_localtz(self,date):
    tz1 = self._context.get('tz')// Value is 'Asia/Calcutta'
    to_zone = tz.gettz(tz1)
    print'to_zone',to_zone // Prints None
    from_zone = tz.tzutc()
    utc = date.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    date = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
    return date
```

Installed python version is 3.7

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Can you share your import statements, and an example of _context since this is a method that starts by getting something from what appears to be a dict on a class?

Also, I'm not quite sure what is happening with the print function in this snippet. It looks like it's being used as a statement when it's a function.

Comment: @Alexander  I updated my code snippet.

Comment: did you consider using ```pytz``` and ```tzlocal``` instead of dateutil and check if the error happens there as well? According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156597/how-can-i-convert-windows-timezones-to-timezones-pytz-understands) you sould be fine with those packages.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.gettz)

> On Windows, the standard is extended to include the Windows-specific
>   zone names provided by the operating system:
>
> ```
> >>> gettz('Egypt Standard Time')
> tzwin('Egypt Standard Time')
> ```

and

> name – A time zone name (IANA, or, on Windows, Windows keys), ...

So I think your `tz1` should be `India Standard Time` (at least based on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values).

Comment: Madar, Thank you for the reply.  Since i am using the same code for both, how can i detect the os and convert these values?

Comment: That's a different question. Though, https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal should help with that.

Comment: This should be helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218506/how-to-get-system-timezone-setting-and-pass-it-to-pytz-timezone

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will work on `*nix` and `Windows`:

```py
import os
import subprocess
from dateutil import tz
TZ_LOCAL = tz.gettz()
if os.name == 'nt':
    sTZ = subprocess.check_output('tzutil /g').decode('utf-8')
    TZ_LOCAL = tz.gettz(sTZ)
```

To be honest, I'm kind of surprised that Python does not do this automatically with `tz.gettz()`. You would figure that the local timezone would be a key bootstrap artifact to preload.

If I raise a ticket for this, I'll link it here for others to upvote.