# is there a way to get the all the list of windows timezones and convert them to iana time zones in python

Tags: python, timezone

trying to get windows timezones in a dropdown list and when user user a timezone I'll pass this input to python where it can convert to iana time like below

Chennai Kolkata Mumbai New Delhi --> Asia/Calcutta

Comment: `Chennai Kolkata Mumbai New Delhi` is not a time zone name Windows uses. You can get those e.g. from [Unicode CLDR](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr) [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

Comment: Also, could you please clarify, how this question is different from your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70994789/10197418) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71012475/10197418)? The first one indicates you're working with a "time zone description", not a time zone name. The second one already has an answer which I think is a viable solution.