# How to convert a timezone name like "Eastern European Standard Time" to a tz database name in Python?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

How would I convert timezone names like "Eastern European Standard Time" to the tz database name (e.g. Europe/Kaliningrad)? Best would be a simple function from a library.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer  your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I think the OP is looking for [How can I convert windows timezones to timezones pytz understands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156597/how-can-i-convert-windows-timezones-to-timezones-pytz-understands) since that seems to be a Windows-specific tz name.

Answer (score 0):

This time zone belongs to a set of countries that use this timezone:

Europe:
Bulgaria
Estonia
Finland
Greece
Latvia
Lithuania
Moldova
Romania
Turkey
Ukraine
Asia:
Cyprus
Gaza Strip
Lebanon
Syria
West Bank
Russia:
Kaliningrad
Africa:
Egypt
Libya

However, for code use, you have to use the Eastern Europe Timezone accepted by libraries like timezone in python or moment in Nodejs:

`Europe/Kyiv`
`Africa/Cairo`