# Django: How to make a datetime object aware of the timezone in which it was created?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, timezone

I am running a program that requests ocean tide data from a remote server. The `time` and `date` of this tide data is being computed based on my machine's local time zone. I want to use these local dates and times to create a `datetime` object, which I will then save in a Django model.

```
datetime_obj = datetime(loc_year, loc_month, loc_date, loc_hour, loc_minute)
```

How do I ensure that the `datetime` object is aware that it was created based on a local time zone, before posting it to Django?

I guess, I would want it to look like this before posting it:

```
datetime_obj = datetime(loc_year, loc_month, loc_date, loc_hour, loc_minute, loc_timezone)
```

How do I get the local timezone of my machine dynamically? And how to I ensure that all users see the time converted to their own local timezone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the Olson TZ name for the local timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669938/get-the-olson-tz-name-for-the-local-timezone)

Comment: In particular, see [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal), which I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16182906/634824)

Comment: *"based on my machine's local time zone"* -- this is the problem. Don't use your local timezone, use UTC timezone instead or POSIX timestamps. If you want; you could store your local time *in addition* to UTC time. See [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/4279).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

First, make sure you're familiar with Django's [documentation on timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/), set `USE_TZ = True`, and install `pytz`.

I don't quite understand where your date is coming from. If it's coming from the server as part of their data (i.e. it represents when the tides were measured), it should either be in UTC already or you will need to know the time zone they are using. If you're creating it, then the simplest thing is just to use [`django.utils.timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) (which returns a timezone-aware datetime) when you create your model instance.

If you really need to manually create it as you've described, follow the usage [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage) or use [`make_aware()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware):

```
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

naive = datetime(loc_year, loc_month, loc_date, loc_hour, loc_minute)
aware = make_aware(naive, timezone=pytz.timezone("Europe/Helsinki"))
# can leave off the timezone parameter if converting to the current timezone
```

The [current timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) will be the default timezone (as defined by the [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone) setting) unless you've used [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) to specify a different one. The default time zone may or may not be the same as the server's system timezone. Getting the system timezone in a format that `pytz` can understand is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365806/2395796).

Finally, ensuring that users see the time converted to their local time zone is non-trivial, as discussed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone):

> The current time zone is the equivalent of the current locale for translations. However, there’s no equivalent of the Accept-Language HTTP header that Django could use to determine the user’s time zone automatically. Instead, Django provides time zone selection functions. Use them to build the time zone selection logic that makes sense for you.

See the examples there for guidance.

Comment: Deprecated since version 4.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware

Comment: @CornelCiobanu: No, just the `is_dst` parameter is deprecated.

Comment: Then, maybe they should state it better (my suggestion). The "Deprecated since version 4.0:" mislead me.

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

timezone.activate(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Comment: Adding some explanation will surely help everyone.

Comment: the first line he chooses the timezone, the second line converts a date into the local timezone.