# Defined field in model not accessible

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following model

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    meeting_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)

    def meeting_datetime(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.meeting_date, self.meeting_time)
```

However, when I try to access the `Meeting` object via `meeting_datetime` I get `Cannot resolve keyword 'meeting_datetime' into field. Choices are: id, meeting_title, meeting_time, meeting_date`.

Why is `meeting_datetime` not an option? Doesn't the `def` create it as a `DateTimeField?` If not, how do I add it as a field, or otherwise access it?

Comment: meeting_datetime is just a model function, it is not treated as a field. Either you need to create a datetime field in your model or you have to compare meeting_time and meeting_date for expected answer.

Comment: @GeoJacob Thanks, so if I add `meeting_datetime = models.DateTimeField()` how can I dynamically add the field value to use `datetime.combine(self.meeting_date, self.meeting_time)`? Do I need to do this in the view when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can rewrite your model as:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
   meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
   meeting_time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
   meeting_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
   meeting_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=False)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.meeting_datetime = datetime.combine(self.meeting_date, self.meeting_time)
      super(Meeting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or

you can filter your queryset as:

```
meeting_objs = Meeting.objects.filter(meeting_date__gt=datetime.date.today(),meeting_time__gt=datetime.datetime.now().time() )
```

Comment: How do I make `meeting_datetime` timezone aware?

Comment: i think this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108634/django-how-to-make-a-datetime-object-aware-of-the-timezone-in-which-it-was-crea

Answer (score 2):

That's because functions aren't represented as fields in Django. You have to call it as a function to get its value (`m.meeting_datetime()`). However, if you really want to access the value without it looking like a function call, you can use the [property decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    meeting_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)

    @property
    def meeting_datetime(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.meeting_date, self.meeting_time)
```

That will allow you to access the `meeting_datetime` function as if it were a property:

```
>>> m = Meeting(...)
>>> m.meeting_datetime
# data
```

That being said, is there a good reason you separated a `DateField` and `TimeField` and didn't just use a single `DateTimeField`?

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then you'd be able to access that field the same as you would above with the decorator example. Except that the value would be stored in your database, while the decorator example's value would be derived only when you access the property.